# Jquery Accordion Menu Issue

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have an accordion menu working on the page, but when I click one of the links, it doesn't go to the corresponding page.

Also, I would love to have it working so that when I click a link, the menu closes, then automatically drops out again when the next page loads.

It's prob better if I just tell you where my code is rather that post it all here?

HTML:

```
<div class="basic" style="float:right;" id="list1b"> <a class="serviceheading">Printing</a>
  <ul id="serviceslist">
    <li><a href="stationery.php">>> Stationery</a></li>
    <li><a href="flyers.php">>> Flyers / Leaflets</a></li>
    <li><a href="brochures.php">>> Brochures</a></li>
    <li><a href="posters.php">>> Posters</a></li>
    <li><a href="calendars.php">>> Calendars</a></li>
    <li><a href="invites.php">>> Invites</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Envelopes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Docket Books</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Menus</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Booklets</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a class="serviceheading">Graphic Design</a>
  <ul id="serviceslist">
    <li><a href="#">>> Print Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Logo Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Brand Development</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Advert Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Product Packaging</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a class="serviceheading">Web Design</a>
  <ul id="serviceslist">
    <li><a href="#">>> Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> E-Commerce Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> SEO - Search Engine Optimization</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Web Marketing (SEO, Banner Ads, Text Ads)</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a class="serviceheading">Signage</a>
  <ul id="serviceslist">
    <li><a href="#">>> PVC Banners</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Pop-up Banners</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Swing Signs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>> Outdoor Signage</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS is located in accordioncss.css

I'm not sure which parts of the script are relevant....I just copied and pasted it :)

Excuse my ignorance guys, I'm still new to this code business

Colm

Comment: I've no idea what happened to my HTML, but obviously it doesn't look like that

Comment: Though I edit for you, you should see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help in order to know how to format code and other staff in your question/answer

Comment: Don't know if this will make a difference, but you should change `>>` in the menu item text to `&gt;&gt;`

Comment: Thanks man, never knew that. It didn't solve the problem though, the links still don't lead anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your links have a `href="#"` code on the html. they should contain the link where you want point them to e.g. `<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>` when you click google would go to google.com website

**update**

```
jQuery('#list1b ul li a').click(function (e){
   var self = $(this);
   setTimeout(function (){window.location.href=self.attr('href')},1500);
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

add above line below this line ====>>> `var wizardButtons = $([]);`

Comment: The top 4 or 5 under "printing" have real links

Comment: it looks like you have removed an id `navigation` so I think `list1b` should have been navigation...

Comment: Thanks man, the links are working now. However, the page is changing when the menu is still closing, is there some way i can make it wait until the menu is fully closed....then change the page....then slide the menu out again?

Yeah I removed loads of navigation stuff....didn't realise it was relevant...oops

Comment: Do I need to add all them navigation lines back in?

Comment: ye i noticed it and updated the link above. `#list1b a` should be `#list1b ul li a` that will escape the headers :)

Comment: what do you mean add all them navigation lines back in?? i don't know what you have removed

Comment: I added a few lines at the bottom of the script, which I had orginally deleted from the tutorial files. They don't seem to change anything though? The navigation stuff I deleted was all just CSS styling for the navigation div, but I don't have a navigation div in my HTML, so I removed all that code.

Comment: thats no problem should not effect anything if you remove them. Although there are a few more things u can remove but just in case u mess things up dont remove if you dont know what you are doing.. google jquery and learn more about it, so you know how it works. btw mark the this question as answered :) by clicking the on the top-left of this answer ;)

Comment: Yeah I found some Jquery and PHP tutorials, making my way through them at the moment....yawn! I hate to be a pest, but any suggestions on how I can make the accordion menu wait until it's fully closed before going to the next page after I click a link? Then reopen once the next page has loaded? If that's too much work, how about this, when I click the "print design" link under "graphic design", when the "print design" page loads, the "printing menu is open....how can i set it so the "graphic design" menu opens?

Comment: that would give a small delay of 1.5 seconds, i wouldnt recommend you to do that though, as this could drive people mad waiting for that thing to close then open the new page. make sure you understand jquery properly then u can use ajax, to do this kind of things as it would be pointless lol :)

Comment: I replaced the first line you gave me with the updated line, now the links don't work again....

Comment: replace the new line i gave u earlier with the three lines

Comment: ok try the new lines that i have updated. i have tested it on your website should work fine

Comment: That's lovely man, I shortened the timeout a bit, but it works. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: another thing remove your website from the question you do not need to advertise it here simply because you shouldnt trust anyone when u ask questions shows ur weak and opportunity to some people :)